# Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Activity#invalidateOptionsMenu

Tags: android

Hi all in my application I am using Navigation drawer and fragments. I had added support library and set min sdk version to 8. But on calling getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu() I am getting error as "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Activity#invalidateOptionsMenu"

My NavigationDrawerFragment class extends from android.support.v4.app.Fragment.  any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in  advance

Comment: You have to set minSdkVersion to 11 in your manifest. no need to always set it to 8. i dont think there are much mobile devices in the market with android api level 8

Comment: In my application I have to give support to min ver 8. So I have to set it to 8.

Comment: how about api level 10 and 9 @AbdulMohsin

Comment: then use supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() method

Comment: @Elltz see here http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

the overall percentage of android versions used :)

Comment: well then if that's your argument then tell android there is no need for support library.. with my little intel in economics - 0.001% of the market is taken into consideration..why? _because is part of the share ratio_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` .. supports api 10 and down..